# How to prevent Re-Import of Existing Records in an Access Saved Import from Excel?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a saved Excel Import in an Access Database that appends 'Payment data' each month to the 'Payments' table.

If someone were to run the import twice by mistake I noticed that Access simply appends the data twice to the table, thereby creating duplicate entries.

How can I prevent the Import from importing entries that already exist in the Table?

**Fields in the Table include:**

- Invoice Number
- Payment Date
- Payment Amount
- Customer ID
- Customer Name
- Payment Type

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the data to temporary table and then copy to main table only new data. Plus unique index, as in @cha answer. But just index is not good solution, it should prevent mistakes, good style - do not generate errors, including key violations

Comment: Thanks Sergey - I'll try that shortly

Comment: The temporary table seems to have fixed the job. Using just the Index seems to still generate the message. Thanks both.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be by implementing a unique index in your table. Only you know what makes the data unique, sometimes it is a unique transaction reference number, or a combination of columns.

The best candidate for the unique index applicable to your situation is [Invoice Number]. If you allow multiple payments for the same invoice (i.e. split invoice) you may need to use two columns for the index: [Invoice Number] + [Payment Date]. When you use two columns for the index make sure they are in the same unique index, not each in separate indices.

Comment: Thanks Cha- i tried this but it still gives the user the option to reimport the existing records as a message pops up saying do you want to proceed. I have raised a separate question about this which you can see here.                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688999/importing-excel-data-into-access-using-index-how-to-prevent-popup-message

Comment: The message will appear, but then after you import them a second message will be displayed advising that records were not  inserted due to violation of primary key

Comment: Hi Cha. I actually want to prevent the users from seeing that message altogether, and have logged a question in the above link related to that because if the records due to be imported were duplicates, I would want it to display a message box to the user saying so instead of confusing the user with a complex access message with Yes/No option. I'll post a pic of the message I am referring to below now

Comment: actually i just realised i can't post a picture in the comments, would you mind referring to the question above to see what I mean please? Thanks